# Calculate average depending on upper right cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I'm trying to get the average depending on another cell.
Basically I want the average of all cells where the value of the upper right cell equals 95.

In this example I would like the average of A3, A6, A7, A8, A9 .

[image]

Comment: What about A1? There can't be any cells offset up to the right from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is tagged with `Excel-2013` so I would suggest the [AVERAGEIF function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AVERAGEIF-function-de90d3d5-49c6-4f88-9376-0ab43c7e4c2b) offsetting the optional *average_range* by one row compared to the *range*.

`=AVERAGEIF(B1:B9,95,A2:A10)`

[image: AVERAGEIF with offset]

While the size of the *average_range* and *average_range* have to stay the same, there is nothing stopping you from offsetting one from the other by rows, columns or both.

Answer (score 1):

Try the functions [sumif](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/sumif-HP005209292.aspx) and [countif](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIF-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US).  In your case:

```
=SUMIF($B$1:$B$9, "=95", $A$1:$A$9)/COUNTIF($B$1:$B$9, "=95")
```

If you put 95 in a cell say C1, then

```
=SUMIF($B$1:$B$9, "=" & $C$1, $A$1:$A$9)/COUNTIF($B$1:$B$9, "=" & $C$1)
```

Of course you can improve upon this (handle when nothing matches) but this is the main idea.

Comment: Shouldn't the *sum_range* used in your `SUMIF` be offset one row from the *range* used for the *criteria*? e.g. `SUMIF($B$1:$B$9, 95, $A$2:$A$10)`

Comment: @Jeeped true but if he really wanted that, he can adjust the formula. Behavior of edge cases should be dealt with by the original poster.